# Returned inputstream from javaFX task is empty

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I've been struggling with this for last two days. What I'm trying to do is load remote images using Task and displaying them.

FXMLController will call Task with number of images(XX) required and Task class will load example.com/1.png example.com/2.png upto example.com/XX.png. Each images will be added to List as inputstream which will be returned at the end of the task. Task's onsucceed method will then create new ImagView with new images for each item in the list.

My code for loading only one image:

**Controller Class**

```
    Task task = new MyTask();
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
            List<InputStream> list = (List<InputStream>) t.getSource().getValue();
            ImageView iv = new ImageView();
            iv.setImage(new Image(list.get(0)));
            ap.getChildren().add(iv);
    .......
    .......
```

**Task Class**

```
public class MyTask extends Task<List> {

List<InputStream> list = new ArrayList<InputStream>();


@Override
protected List<InputStream> call() throws Exception {
    .......
    *-*-*-code to login to website to get image with httpclient-*-*-*

        CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        try {
            HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
            InputStream inputStream = entity1.getContent();
            list.add(inputStream);
            //inputStream has correct image which I verified by
            //writing the stream to file
    .......
    .......
    return list;
```

My problem is image is not displayed. Upon further investigating the inputstreams in list are empty. I tried directly returning only one inputstream without using list still the inputsteram is empty.

(inputstream.isAvailable() returns -1 which makes me believe it is empty.) My task has correct inputstream which I verified by writing the stream to file.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Could you please override the failed() of the task and add the following line to it?   
System.out.println(this.exceptionProperty().getValue()); sometimes this helps me finding a bug or any missing exception in task classes

Comment: Is the InputStream correct in MyTask? Did you try new Image(inputStream) in call() implementation (not to create GUI, just to see if you have the same error from there).

Comment: @zenbeni Like I've said above I created a file with that inputstream and it is working ok.

Comment: I suspect CloseableHttpResponse just closes all inputStream got from getContent() when it closes... So can you try instanciating the image in MyTask before closing CloseableHttpResponse just to confirm it is not that?

Comment: @zenbeni I think you're right. I think a better way would be to read the stream and put it in some other variable. Is there a way to do so apart from using  a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your InputStreams are closed in your Task, so you can't access them anymore after that. To make it work you could read the InputStream objects in your Task, then writing for instance a Base64 string value for each one. Then you return them from the task in your callback to GUI thread, you instanciate an InputStream from the Base64 String, and you can create your Image.

Comment: Is there a built in method to convert inputstream to Base64 string value?

Comment: Found IOUtils library